# Does election #3 have required badges?

Tags: support, election

The Stack Overflow elections have had required badges, and while there was some whining about it, they helped set up a more meaningful bar for participation than just reputation.

Here, though, I'm not arguing for or against badge requirements (we're probably still too young and small for that) - I'm just asking if the current 2012 elections (round 3) have required badges or not.

Comment: In the SO election the badge requirements were explicitly written at the top, they're not here on the Gaming election. There's also one nominee barely above the minimum rep requirement who has none of the badges that were used in the SO election. I think it's pretty safe to say that there are no badge-related restrictions in this election.

Comment: @fabian well it could've been that our customzed election message post got in the way (not unprecedented); I also forgot that required badges were actually enforced by the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to officially confirm what Fabian commented:

No, there are no additional badge requirements for this election.